# Change in IP header length

Tags: ipv4

I read in 2-3 places that length of IP header may change during transit from source to destination with routers in-between. However, no explanation was given as to why it might change.

According to me, the only way the length of IP header could change is when length of options field would change. 
For example, we have record route option where the IP address gets added each time to options field when it passes through each router giving us the entire route from source to destination. So here as IP address is added each time, the length of option field is changing.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Only options change the length of the header.

Comment: But which option changes the length ?

Comment: how will fragmentation change the IP header length ? Only the field value changes or fragmentation offset changes but the amount of bits allocated to fragmentation offset in IP header remains same. Only total length of datagram changes due to fragmentation and not IP header length.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment: of course I should have said RFC 791, which replaced 760, and which differs materially in this specific detail.  To answer the question, some options are copied to each fragment, some appear only in the first fragment.  Some can be inserted or deleted for any reason.  The options eg record route defined in 791 overwrite fields in the header rather than changing length as in 760.  Nevertheless, routers have been known to drop source routing and similar options.

Answer (score -2):

No, it doesn't change

The Header length or size is decided by the number of fields present inside the header like MF, TTL, etc. The fields are decided by the sender itself, routers cannot add or delete fields.

However, routers can change the contents of the fields e.g Record route will can have 0 to 9 IP addresses, but this will not change the length of it

Comment: There are a number of IP options that can be added to the header, changing its length - see RFC 791. Record Route is one of those options (and long obsolete).

Comment: if header length was constant why would anyone put header length field in the header? IPv6 header is constant and it does not have a header length field.

Comment: @Zac67 Suppose the record route recorded 5 IP addresses, will the HL increase by say 5 units as compared to 0 addresses recorded?

Comment: The header length is determined by the value in the four-bit IHL field that is the number of 32-bit words in the header, and it can change if options change. The header is a minimum of 20 octets (IHL=5) and a maximum of 60 octets (IHL=15).

Comment: @RonMaupin Is it possible for the options to change dynamically at the router if the user doesn't set them in the first place?

Comment: @RonMaupin ... for IPv4. IPv6 uses a chained *Next Header* concept, either indicating the payload's *IP protocol number* directly or the extension header type with the last extension header indicating the payload type.

Comment: IPv4 headers are completely rewritten in the path all the time. NAT does that as a matter of course, and anything can happen to an IPv4 header along the path.

Comment: IPv6 speeds up packet forwarding by having a fixed header length (40 octets). It uses extension headers that are forbidden to be added or removed in the path, and all except one are only for the destination, not the routers in the path.

Comment: @Zac67, this answer seems to be about IPv4 because it mentions fields like TTL that are IPv4-only.